# How to set a condition in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a web app that displays a monthly event calendar in PHP. For the input, I am using HTML to create a form. The input consists of Month, a Year, an event and a day on which the event occurred. I am using input type "month" for the month and year, "text" for the event and "number" for the day on which event occurred. I want to set the condition on "number" in such a way that its max limit depends on the month chosen. For example - If the user chooses February, then the max limit on the "number" should be 28, if the user chooses January, then the max limit should be 31 and so on.

I think I should put in  from javascript but I have no idea about the syntax. The max limit is set to 31 currently

```html
<form action="Calender.php" method="POST" id="Month Calender" name="Month Calender">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Month,Year and Day</legend>
          <label>Month and Year</label>
              <input type="month"  required>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
                <legend>Events</legend>
                <label>Event 1</label>
                <input id="i1" type="text" maxlength="60">
                <label>Day Number</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" max="31">
        </fieldset>
</form>

The limit should depend on the month chosen but right now it is set to 31.
```

Comment: This is something you will need to do with JavaScript

Comment: Yes [Javascript form validation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/form-validation-using-html-javascript/) is your best bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```js
document.getElementById("mmmyy").addEventListener("change",function() {
  const [yyyy, mm] = this.value.split("-");
  var maxDate = new Date(yyyy,mm,0,12,0,0,0).getDate(); // months are 0 based so mm is NEXT month but day 0 is last day of this month
  console.log(maxDate)
  document.getElementById("daynum").setAttribute("max",maxDate);
})
```

```html
<form action="Calender.php" method="POST" id="Month Calender" name="Month Calender">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Month,Year and Day</legend>
    <label>Month and Year</label>
    <input type="month" id="mmmyy" required>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Events</legend>
    <label>Event 1</label>
    <input id="i1" type="text" maxlength="60">
    <label>Day Number</label>
    <input type="number" id="daynum" min="1" max="31">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Using a select:

```js
document.getElementById("month").addEventListener("change",function() {
  const mm = this.selectedIndex; // again this will be 1 more 
  if (mm===0) return;
  const yyyy = new Date().getFullYear(); // this year
  var maxDate = new Date(yyyy,mm,0,12,0,0,0).getDate(); // months are 0 based so mm is NEXT month but day 0 is last day of this month
  console.log(maxDate)
  document.getElementById("daynum").setAttribute("max",maxDate);
})
```

```html
<form action="Calender.php" method="POST" id="Month Calender" name="Month Calender">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Period</legend>
    <label>Month</label>
    <select id="month" required>
    <option value="0">Please select
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">Mar</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">Jun</option>
    <option value="7">Jul</option>
    <option value="8">Aug</option>
    <option value="9">Sep</option>
    <option value="10">Oct</option>
    <option value="11">Nov</option>
    <option value="12">Dec</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Events</legend>
    <label>Event 1</label>
    <input id="i1" type="text" maxlength="60">
    <label>Day Number</label>
    <input type="number" id="daynum" min="1" max="31">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I *like* your clever approach of identifiying the last day of a given month: `new Date(2019,12,0,12)` addresses the "day before" January  1, 2020: the month-number 12 is "one month after december" and the day-numer 0 is the day before the first of that month.

Comment: Why the downvote? Baffles me each time why downvoters take time to register their displeasure but not to let the rest of us know so we can improve whatever it was that was not ok in their eyes!

Comment: Completely baffled by it too!

Comment: How should I modify your solution if my months are in input type "select" and options range from "January" to "December"?

Comment: See update - I added a solution for a select  - assuming this year always

Comment: I did not downvote mplugjan. I have less reputation so my votes do not show publicly. I changed my mind because it  seemed easy to me to work with PHP form in input type "select". I am sorry if it caused any inconvenience

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this using the [onChange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) attribute, along with Javascript from validation.
Change `<input type="number" min="1" max="31">` to have the `onChange` attribute, and an `id` attribute, like so:

`<input id="dayInput" type="number" min="1" max="31" onChange='validate()' />`

Then Have the following script in your html file somewhere

```
<script>
function validate()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("dayInput");
    if(x.value > 0) {
        alert("Change your conditions in this area of the script. Also don't use alerts for debugging, it's bad practice, use console.log() instead");
    }

}
</script>
```